# Query performance issue with ST_Intersects()

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-performance

Following query is taking 3.06min to execute. How to speedup this query? How to use existing index column while executing query?

```
SELECT samples_collected.talukname,sample_count,TotalSamples from 
(
SELECT a.talukname talukname, COUNT (DISTINCT b.globalid) sample_count
FROM village a, gridpoint_1 b ,gridpoint_1__attach c
WHERE  st_intersects(a.shape,b.shape)
and b.globalid=c.rel_globalid
and  a.districtname='Bagalkot'
GROUP BY a.talukname
) samples_collected,
(
SELECT a.talukname talukname,COUNT (DISTINCT b.globalid) TotalSamples
FROM village a
INNER JOIN
gridpoint_1 b ON  st_intersects(a.shape,b.shape)
WHERE a.districtname='Bagalkot'
GROUP BY a.talukname
) total
WHERE samples_collected.talukname=total.talukname;
```

Comment: Run `explain analyze (your_select_query)` and use http://explain.depesz.com/ to analyse the result

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the hard work twice and that is obviously inefficient: `ST_Intersects(a.shape, b.shape)` in both sub-queries. Rather than using two sub-queries you should put them together and then do the different `count()`s over a partition:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.talukname, 
       count(DISTINCT b.globalid) OVER w AS totalsamples,
       count(DISTINCT c.rel_globalid) OVER w AS sample_count,
FROM village a
JOIN gridpoint_1 b ON ST_Intersects(a.shape, b.shape)
LEFT JOIN gridpoint_1__attach c ON c.rel_globalid = b.globalid
WHERE a.districtname = 'Bagalkot'
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY a.talukname);
```

So you take the villages in the district Bagalkot and join that to the grid points. The third table is `LEFT JOIN`ed, meaning that the value of `ref_globalid` is `NULL` where there is no corresponding value equal to `b.globalid`. Then you can do a `count()` on `b.globalid` for `totalsamples` and on `c.ref_globalid` for sample_count (`NULL` values are not counted).

This will be up to twice as fast as the original. On the use of indexes nothing can be said without detailed information about your tables, but in general you should put a `gist` index on the `geometry` columns.